# Solution for a system of linear ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given a system of linear ODEs by

$$\mathbf{y}'(t)=\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{y}(t)$$

where $\mathbf{y}(t)$ is a vector of $n$ equations and $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$

What is the relationship of the solution of a transformed system
$\mathbf{g}'(t)=\kappa\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{g}(t)$
to the solutions of the original, i.e. how to go from a solution of the transformed to the original.

My initial guess is $\mathbf{y}(t)=\mathbf{g}(t/\kappa)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since the system equations are globally Lipschitz, the solutions are unique (from the same starting point), so if we let
$z(t) = g({t \over \kappa})$, we see that
$z'(t) = {1 \over \kappa} g'({t \over \kappa}) = A g(t) = A z(t)$.

Assuming that $y(0) = g(0)$, we see that $y,z$ satisfy the same differential equation and have the same initial condition, hence $z=y$.

Comment: I believe I have a typo. that I will fix when I hlget to my laptop.